# Google OR-Tools Set Fixed Start Location and Allow Arbitrary End Location

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

For a VRP in or-tools, is there a way to have vehicles start at some fixed locations, but allow for arbitrary end locations?

The documentation https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/routing_tasks#setting-start-and-end-locations-for-routes and https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/routing_tasks#allowing-arbitrary-start-and-end-locations show present how to set custom or arbitrary start/end locations respectively.

My question is can we combine them both? i.e. custom start location and arbitrary end location(and vice-versa)?

Thank you

Comment: Hello! Where you able to solve this? I am tryingn to accomplish this same use case. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to tweak your distance matrix to have a zero length from any normal node to the end nodes, and ignore this last arc when reading the solution.

Comment: In this case wouldn't any node be a candidate for end node? To clarify, if we have 10 nodes (1-10) and 3 vehicles with start nodes as 1,2, and 3. I'm thinking all the remaining nodes (4-10) would be candidates for end nodes. In this instance, how would we set the matrix up?

Comment: Create a dummy end node that you set as the vehicle's end node. Then when constructing the distance matrix, set the distance from any node to the dummy node to zero.

Comment: @Laurent, do you have a simple bit of code to express this, i think this would be a great feature especially for mvrp / mtsp